# Combine sentences with "although"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

The question goes as follows:

> Make a sentence from the given sentences using 'although'.
>
> a. We've known each other for a long time.
>
> b. We are not very good friends.

The intended answer is 'Although we've known each other for a long time, we are not very good friends'.

Some of my students ask why not 'Although we are not very good friends, we've known each other for a long time.'

Do you think both are right?

Answer (score 3):

Both are acceptable, but they have subtly different meanings.

*Although* indicates that a particular situation does not have an expected effect:

> Although we've known each other for a long time, we are not very good friends.
>   *We might be expected to be good friends following a long acquaintance, but have not become so.*
>
> Although we are not very good friends, we've known each other for a long time.
>   *It might be expected that because we are not good friends, we've only known each other for a short time, not long enough to form a friendship. In fact, that's not the case.*

*Although* may also (and possibly more idiomatically) occur in the middle of each sentence, where it makes for a slightly stronger indication of unexpectedness:

> We are not very good friends, although we've known each other for a long time.
>
> We've known each other for a long time, although we are not very good friends.

And if you use *even though* in the middle of the sentence, the unexpectedness is even greater.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically both are correct, however each sentence brings a different message with it.

'Although we have known each other for a long time, we are not very good friends' implicitly emphasizes on the point that you are not good friends overshadowing the fact that you have know each other for quite some time.

'Although we are not very good friends, we have known each other for a long time.' emphasizes on the point that you have known each other for quite some time overshadowing the point of not being very good friends.

Based on the context of use and the message you intend to convey from the sentence, you may use either of them.

Answer (score -1):

*Although we've known each other for a long time, we are not very good friends*

*Although we are not very good friends, we've known each other for a long time*'

Both are correct but I'd be tempted to use the word 'acquaintance' to replace the cliched  "not very good friends".  'Acquaintance' suggests a neutrality in explaining why we aren't very good friends.

Comment: I wouldn't say cliched - you probably feel uncomfortable with it because it's often used as a euphemism, for people who aren't very good friends - that is, to say, they actually don't like each other. And if someone's made the choice to say that they're "not very good friends", it's possible that it's because they're friends, which I would distinguish from acquaintance.